Can we find the minimum of the following expression without using calculus? $t^4+ (t-3)^2$
I would appreciate if somebody could help me with the following problem
Q: Can we find the minimum of the following equation without using differentiation?
$$t^4+ (t-3)^2$$
I tried many methods, including Cauchy's inequality, but I couldn't find the answer.

This is an expression, not an equation nor an inequality.  My only trick without differentiation is to make it a single square plus a constant but I don't see how.

Yes, I have corrected it.

Note that
$$t^4+(t-3)^2=(t-1)^2(t^2+2t+4)+5.$$
Since $t^2+2t+4=(t+1)^2+3>0$, the minimum value of the entire expression is $5$, achieved at $t=1$.

How did you come up with the idea to transform the equation like above? That's a very good approach. Thank you very much.

@Young Mostly reverse engineering. I checked a few values and realized that $(1,5)$ is probably the minimum. Then to prove it, I tried manipulating the equation into something nonnegative plus 5, so after subtracting 5, I found that the resulting quartic indeed had 1 as a root, allowing it to factor into something nice.

I see. Thanks for the reply.
